# Reboot loop after failed SLES SUSE update

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, opensuse, elilo

Currently when I start the machine I get a black screen with ELILO BOOT and the after 2 files finish loading the machine reboots by itself.

Originally SLES 11 was running on it, I tried updating from the command line and it caused this issue.

From rescue mode, I'm able to see the EFI partition and the files inside it. elilo.conf in that partition seems to still have info from the old SLES 11.

I tried upgrading to Sles 11 SP4, and 12 but when it comes to updating the boot loader SLES 12 got stuck.

From the repair mode of SLES 11 SP4 I'm unable to install a new bootloader, as I keep getting errors.

What do you suggest in this case please? How do I know why the machine can't boot? How do I update the boot loader?

Thanks